# LaTeX formal letter: signature align left

Tags: formatting, latex, letter

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to fix this signature. Right now, it is right-hand justified, and I want to make it left-hand justified. I am still pretty green when it comes to LaTeX and formatting documents in it. It is probably something really simple.

Right now, I suspect the "\raggedright" command will have something to do with it. Just not sure exactly where.

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{kpfonts, sans}
\usepackage{url}

\title{title}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{First \ Last}
\addrfrom{%
    \today\\[10pt]
Who from \\
Street \\
City, State
}
\phonefrom{(123) 456-7890}
\emailfrom{email@mail.com}
\addrto{%
Division\\
Organization\\
Street\\
City, State}


\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

*Letter content*

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Bonus points if you know how to get rid of the black bars at the top and bottom, or reduce the header so that it is not taking up a huge amount of room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh... there's really no need to set any kind of letter using the `letter` or [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) document class. As you have now come to notice, adjustments are not always all that easy. So I present an alternative, by just setting a letter as-is in the `article` document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\pagestyle{empty}% No page headers/footers
\begin{document}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  \today\\[10pt]
  Who from \\
  Street \\
  City, State \\
  Phone: (123) 456-7890 \\
  Email: email@mail.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip% or \vspace{20pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Division\\
  Organization\\
  Street\\
  City, State
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

To whom it may concern,

\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

Sincerely,

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

First~Last

\end{document}
```

In my opinion, the code is far more readable than using the `letter` or `newlfm` interface where some of the document content is scattered in the preamble and inside the document. Moreover, the [`newlfm.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/newlfm.cls) is void of *any* proper coding indentation, making debugging a painstaking task.

The [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is used to adjust the spacing in terms of the page layout.